# Compare current date with date in data lists (don't compare for the second of date)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to compare 2 date (don't compare for the second of date): current date and date in data list.
If currentDate === the date in lists -> field isCurrentDate will change.

Example:

```
const currentdate = new Date();

works: any[]=[

{
id: 1,
dateWork:'2022-10-08T10:30:04.000Z',
isCurrentDate: false,
},

{
id: 1,
dateWork:'2022-10-07T11:30:04.000Z',
isCurrentDate: false,
},

{
id: 1,
dateWork:'2022-10-06T13:30:04.000Z',
isCurrentDate: false,
}
]
```

Comment: The question is incomplete. What did you try ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Question is not related to angular nor typescript, it's only about programming in javascript. Convert `dateWork` property to Date object and compare with current date. Use datetime libraries like moment.js or date-fns, or stay with built-in Date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
currentdate.setSeconds(0,0)

var works=[

  { id: 1, dateWork:'2022-10-08T10:30:04.000Z', isCurrentDate: false, },
  
  { id: 1, dateWork:'2022-10-07T11:30:04.000Z', isCurrentDate: false, },
  
  { id: 1, dateWork:'2022-10-06T13:30:04.000Z', isCurrentDate: false, } ]
  
  works.forEach(function (value, index) {

    var dateWork = (new Date(value.dateWork))
    dateWork.setSeconds(0,0)
    if(currentdate.getTime()===dateWork.getTime())
    {
      works[index].isCurrentDate=true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: TO wants to ignore the second, this won't ignore the second

Comment: I did not pay attention to the second. But the problem is solved with .setSeconds(0,0). Thank you for your attention